# Multiple data in one user input

Tags: python, loops, user-input

I am having a trouble with multiple numbers in one user input. The idea is to multiply each user`s number with a predetermined one. Does it even possible to loop through?

```
in1 = input('Enter ')
in2 = 10

def count():
    s = [x*in2 for x in in1]
    print(s)

count()
```

With input like this '5 5 5' terminal gave me this:

```
['5555555555', '          ', '5555555555', '          ', '5555555555']
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `s = [int(x)*int2 for x in in1 if x != ' ']`, they're treated like strings not integers hence you get 10 5's, instead of 50 when multiplying

Comment: each number multiplied on 10: '50, 50, 50'

Comment: `s = [int(x)*int2 for x in in1 if x != '']` does not work. It gave me this `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: It should be `in2` not `int2`.

Comment: i`ve change that after copy/paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `input()` treats it as a `str`, using `split()`  to have them space-separated, Convert each `str` to `int` and then multiply it by `in2`. Also, avoid using keywords as function names:

```
in1 = input('Enter ').split()              # ['5', '5', '5']
in2 = 10

def func():
    return [int(x)*in2 for x in in1 if x]

print(func())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter 5 5 5
[50, 50, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also be passing parameters into your function and returning a result:

```
def multiplyUp(userInput, factor):
    return [int(x) * factor for x in userInput]

in1 = input('Enter ').split()
in2 = 10

print(multiplyUp(in1, in2))
```

**NB:** code shamelessly stolen from @DirtyBit